# Why am I getting an "ERROR Command errored out with exit status 1" when installing the ratfun package for python 3.6?

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am trying to install the **ratfun** package for python 3.6 with

`pip3.6 install ratfun`

but am getting the ERROR shown in code down below.

Doing
`sudo pip3.6 install ratfun`
or updating setuptools
`pip3.6 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`
doesn't help. I am using the latest version of `pip3.6`.
From other threads I understood that 
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:`
can in general be linked to some denied permissions, but I don't know how to fix it. Thanks for any ideas!

I am using macOS 10.15.2

````
  Downloading ratfun-2.6.tar.gz (56 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 56 kB 1.2 MB/s 
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/nc/bzf21l914zq832bjwd5lc4wh0000gn/T/pip-install-7zqss5yi/ratfun/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/nc/bzf21l914zq832bjwd5lc4wh0000gn/T/pip-install-7zqss5yi/ratfun/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/nc/bzf21l914zq832bjwd5lc4wh0000gn/T/pip-install-7zqss5yi/ratfun/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/nc/bzf21l914zq832bjwd5lc4wh0000gn/T/pip-install-7zqss5yi/ratfun/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/private/var/folders/nc/bzf21l914zq832bjwd5lc4wh0000gn/T/pip-install-7zqss5yi/ratfun/setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Answer (score 0):

The package really doesn't have `setup.py`. It's not a `pip`-installable package. You can download it, unpack and try to run `python clnum_setup.py install`. But please note the package was last released in 2009 so I'd not expect it to run with Python 3. Try Python 2.7.

Comment: I downloaded and unpacked the package and when I run `python clnum_setup.py install` I get: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'clnum_setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` . Where should I move the unpacked package so that python finds 'clnum_setup.py' ?

Comment: It's in the unpacked directory. `cd ratfun-2.6`

Comment: Thanks! As I moved to `ratfun-2.6` and tried to install it, I first got an error `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`. As elsewhere suggested I then reinstalled Xcode and updated the command line developer tools. Now, as I am running `python clnum_setup.py install`, I am getting the following error :

Comment: `building 'clnum.clnum' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c clnum/src/clnum.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/clnum/src/clnum.o
clnum/src/clnum.cpp:30:10: fatal error: 'cln/cln.h' file not found`

Comment: `#include <cln/cln.h>
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`

Comment: Unfortunately `sudo -E python clnum_setup.py install` doesn't help. Do you have an idea what is the source of this problem?

Comment: See *Installation* at http://calcrpnpy.sourceforge.net/clnumManual.html